# How do I fix a "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch" in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, async-await, stream, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-webassembly

The code below, runs for about fifteen seconds on the "***dataFs = await _Http.GetStreamAsync(BODIST_DATA_HTTPNAME)***" line before failing with a "***System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch***".

```
        public async Task<Double> EffectivePipCount(HttpClient _Http, Int64 _PositionId)
        {
            Double retVal = Double.NaN;
            using (Stream locnFs = await _Http.GetStreamAsync(BODIST_LOCATION_FILENAME)
                            , dataFs = await _Http.GetStreamAsync(BODIST_DATA_FILENAME))
            {
                retVal = EffectivePipCount(_PositionId, locnFs, dataFs);
            }
            return retVal;
        }
```

The file in question is about four gigabytes in size. 
 
This is in Blazor WebAssembly app, so I want an Http equivalent to a FileStream, where I can seek and then read the hundreds of bytes I want. Small files in the same directory work fine.  
 
If the problem is a timeout because of the file size, what should I be using instead of ***HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()***?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that GetStreamAsync() pulls down the whole file. Using http.GetFromJsonAsync solves the problem.